# Search a text file for a word then print the next word from text file?

Tags: python, io

- The text file lists words in a single column
- Open this file
- search the file for 'word'
- print the the next word from the file after finding 'word'

I've been looking for hours for this syntax, but it must be so simple nobody feels the need to have it written anywhere. Please help

Comment: Have you read this: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 1):

Basic file read:

```
ifs = open('myfile', 'r')
for line in ifs:
    # do your stuff
```

Of course, you'll have to deal with special cases of 'word' isn't in the file or it's on the last line in the file.

Answer (score 1):

If the text file is small, you can simply do:

```
with open('myfile', 'r') as f:
    f = f.read().splitlines() # no trailing '\n' character as opposed to readlines

ind = f.index('word')
if ind < len(f) - 1:
    print(f[ind+1])
```

If the text file is large, you can read it line by line like this:

```
with open('myfile', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == 'word':                
            try:
                print(next(f))
            except StopIteration:
                pass
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
with open('input') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if line.strip().lower() == 'word':
            line = next(in_file)
            print line.strip()
```

The above code on an input file as:

```
word
hello
how
are
you 
word
nadal
```

prints:

```
hello
nadal
```

Hope it helps